# No option of Windows Boot Manager in BIOS

Tags: windows, boot, grub

I had a dual boot Ubuntu + Windows 10, both are on separate disk. I accidentally deleted the disk that contains the Ubuntu from Windows Disk Manager. So I thought I would just delete the GRUB, and I followed the step here (the accepted answer): https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader.

When I go into BIOS, I can see the Windows Boot Manager is there, so I set the boot priority to that.

But... when I removed the disk that used to contain the Ubuntu, suddenly there is no option to boot into Windows Boot Manager anymore in the BIOS. I thought the Windows Boot Manager lives in my Windows 10 disk?

So... what would I need to do, to be able to boot into my Windows? And also to be able to physically remove my Ubuntu disk?

Also: The Windows disk does not contain much (all my data, medias are on separate physical HDD), if things can be fixed faster by just reformatting, I'd do it.

Comment: Have you looked at your Related articles on the right-side of this page ?

Comment: @Farid go for complete re-install; also remove all other drivers before booting from win usb {to install win}

Comment: @vssher I did. None worked. After 4 hours of reading and trying many things, I decided to just re-install everything, save time and energy :)